# read from a file which is deleted

Tags: c, linux, file, filesystems, libc

I wrote a small program in C where I opened a file successfuly, then called sleep for 20 sec. In that 20 sec I deleted the open file using rm from shell. After sleep the program reads the data successfully and prints it on screen.

```
int bytes_read;
FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/file", "r");
sleep(20);
bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, 5, fp);
buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
printf("%s", buf);
```

I expected it to read 0 bytes, but it prints the actual data in the file. What is the explanation behind this behaviour.

Comment: The data on the disk isn't eradicated, only the inode is removed. And that also only after all open handles on the file are closed.

Comment: Is this also true if the file is renamed?

Comment: Same principle. You have opened a file, the OS won't pull it away from under your feet.

Comment: What if it was renamed and user priviledges changed so earlier user can not read it. Can we still read data? If the new user adds some sensitive information, isnt it a security problem?

Comment: I have to admit I don't know how that is handled.

Comment: The permissions are checked on open (`man 2 open`) to obtain a file descriptor for the desired access (e.g. O_RDWR).  Once the file descritor is created then the inode is not considered again (for that file descriptor).  If the process tried to open the file a second time then the new permissions would apply.  It is only a security problem if you expect anything else to happen!

Comment: Consider another scenario:  process running under root opens a file descriptor to a file only root can access.  Program fails to close the file descriptor.  This process does a `fork` followed by `execve` which inherits the open file descriptors, but the second process is running under a differerent user id which should not have access to the file, but could use the open fd.  Security issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In linux and other POSIX systems you don't delete files. You just remove an inode from a directory. As long as there is a file descriptor open on a file it will not be deleted. Only when the last link to the inode and the last open file descriptor went away.

Comment: What's curious about this is that you can be in a situation where your files still exist (while the program is running), but you just have absolutely no way of rescuing them once you deleted the directory entries. I've been told that there are security reasons why the kernel doesn't provide an interface to find files via their open descriptors, and that you could get that behaviour by making an appropriate kernel module.

Comment: On Linux you can find out the file name from the fd by tracking the symbolic links in /proc/$$/fd (where $$ is your pid) - try it using `ls -l`.  In the version I just checked (CentOS 6.3) it also says that the file has been deleted, but the fd is still open.

Comment: The sentence "delete an inode from a directory" is nonsense.  inodes do not exist in a directory.  Two paths in different directories can be links to the same inode.  Unlinking a path from an inode (which is what `rm` does) does remove the link from the directory, but the inode will not be deleted from the file system until the last reference to it is removed.

Comment: UNIX "loses" files.   When you remove a file, it is unlinked from the directory from which you deleted it.   The system keeps track of the number of directories pointing at the file. When this number becomes zero, the file will, at the system's leisure, be overwritten as its sectors get redeployed.